# How do I customize Laravel Breeze's message about a password being compromised?

Tags: laravel, passwords, user-experience, laravel-breeze

**Edit: This issue should be solved in Laravel 10.33 and up. Refer to the comment below for more information.**

I'm working on an app using Laravel Breeze. When I try to create an unsafe password (something that has been leaked/pwned such as `Password1!`), I receive this validation error message:

> The given password has appeared in a data leak. Please choose a different password.

From my standpoint, the message is pretty straightforward, but from an end-user standpoint, I'm afraid it is not so clear. Indeed, the end-user reading this message might wonder if the data was leaked on the site I'm working on and feel like the site being visited isn't safe when this actually is extra safety being provided. This is why I want to customize my message for something like this:

> The given password was part of a leak at some point on the Web. As a security measure, we have blocked its use on this site.

**Technologies:**

- PHP 8.1
- Laravel 10.10
- Laravel Breeze 1.21

**What I have tried so far in my RegisteredUserController**

```
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $rules = [
            [other rules],
            'password'      => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->letters()->numbers()->symbols()->uncompromised()],
        ];

        $messages = [
            'password.uncompromised' => 'The given password was part of a leak at some point on the Web. As a security measure, we have blocked its use on this site.',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);

        Auth::login($user = User::create([
            [other stuff]
            'password'      => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]));

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        (new MyController)->store($request);

        return redirect()->route('register_step_2');
    }
```

**What happens when I use the code above**

When I use the code provided above, the default error message is what gets passed to the user interface, not my custom message.

Comment: Is that a built-in feature of breeze? I just tried it and with `Password1!` and it didn't work.

Comment: @YusufBouzekri it's meant to be part of Laravel see [validating passwords](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-passwords)

Comment: I did what the documenation said and it worked like a charm, insane how much cool stuff laravel has to offer @apokryfos

Comment: Did you try removing the `uncompromised` in the `Password` chain method and instead add it after `confirmed` as a string element?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I just this. This gave me a 500 error. I didn't find any reference in the documentation about the possibility of using `uncompromised` as a string instead of a method to block compromised passwords.

Comment: If it still fails, try to change the validation.php https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#specifying-custom-messages-in-language-files

Comment: Not sure if it is included in the file. But you can check it

Comment: Just for your information: what you stated was actually a bug which was solved recently (few weeks after you asked this question) in Laravel 10.33 ([Pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/48928)). So you can translate those messages in the classic way in Laravel 10.33 and up-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is seems to be the case for not only `uncompromised()` but all the remaining built-in methods of the custom rules object (used in [Password.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Password.php)) and the documentation does not cover this case at all.

The only workaround I found so far for these built-in methods is to run `php artisan lang:publish`. You will then see a **lang/** directory added to the root of your application where you can locate the key in the associative array of the **validation.php** file and change its value to whatever you want:

[image]

And here a short piece of code I used in **RegisteredUserController.php**:

```
public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $messages = [
            // For non built-in methods, this works as mentioned in the documentation
            'name.required' => 'We need your name',
        ];
        $rules = [
            'name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(5)->uncompromised()]
        ];
        $request->validate($rules, $messages);
        // The rest of code      
    }
```

And here is the result of the above code and changes:

[image]

Comment: This was actually a bug and solved in this [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/48928) (few weeks after this question was asked). In Laravel 10.33 and up, you can solve the OP's problem in the classic way, instead